# RTL Stylesheet Confusion with WordPress

Tags: php, css

All I understand about RTL is that some languages are written right-to-left.

In a WordPress theme, what role does the `rtl.css` stylesheet have? I was under the impression that the only difference was paragraph alignment, but the WordPress themes that I have seen have massive `rtl.css` files.

What other requirements are there of CSS to provide true RTL support?

Comment: rtl.css is copy of main template css file used for rtl supported themes. This is almost exact copy of regular style with changes concerning css properties such as direction, text-align, floats and sometimes image placement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guy explains it fairly well for wordpress (video, no transcript): [Yoav Farhi: Right to Left WordPress](http://wordpress.tv/2010/05/01/yoav-farhi-right-to-left-themes-sf10/).

The Wordpress Manual (Codex) has as well some information regarding [Right to Left Language Support](http://codex.wordpress.org/Right_to_Left_Language_Support).

Answer (score 1):

See the docs http://codex.wordpress.org/Right_to_Left_Language_Support and http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/tags/rtl-language-support for examples.